# Best way for C# desktop app to Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I developed a desktop C# app with WPF UI.
What would be the best way to make this as a web application (I'm very new to web devlopment)?

The initial programm gets input via the UI and than does some calculations with the API of a 3D CAD-software. Afterwards, the results are visualized in the UI dashboard.
For that process I created classes and functions that get executed when the user clicks the "Calculate" button.

Can I - broadly speaking - put the whole code behind of the "Calculate" button in a Http Get method of a controller?
And what framework would be the best fit, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API?

Most of the ASP.NET tutorials I watched dealt mostly with CRUD operations and databases, but I don't need one in the first place.
The UI I'd like to do with vue.js and JavaScript (if that even matters).

Answer (score 1):

It`s unnecessary to use CRUD operations if you don`t need them. You can simply to create ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Api, they are same just different boiler  plate. If you create asp.net mvc, you can delete the things wich don`t needed.

You say you  want Vue.js for frontend so you need web api in  backend!
I thin on creation asp.net api by default you don`t have any database. So you will use only controllers and other functions  wich you have

Regards